# How can I listen for data updates on the Parse server?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I'm new to Parse so I'm building a test project to test out various capabilities. I was successful in building upstream data synchronisation, where I can push data to the Parse server. But I'm totally lost on how to enable downstream data sync.

I want to make it so that my iOS app receives updates from the server when there's new/updated data. For example, after insert a new record using the `parse.com` interface, I want to get notified and be able to then pull the new data.

My Parse setup:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
   Parse.enableLocalDatastore()
   Parse.setApplicationId("ID", clientKey: "KEY")
   return true
}
```

My data transfer so far relied on using instances of `PFObject`.

```
userParseObject = PFObject(className: "User")

userParseObject["dateCreated"] = dateCreated
userParseObject["dateOfLastLogin"] = dateOfLastLogin
userParseObject["name"] = name

userParseObject.saveInBackgroundWithBlock {
   (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
   if (success) {} else {}
}
```

How do I listen for CRUD operations on the Parse server?

Comment: You can have your iOS app register for push notifications, and use Parse Cloud Code to send a silent push notification when there's a data change you want the iOS app to know about. Alternatively, you can poll for changes every N minutes, but you probably don't want that.

Comment: But does that mean I have to be an Apple dev and do tons of setup before I can get there? I'm referring to this article https://www.parse.com/tutorials/ios-push-notifications

Comment: You certainly need to pay $99 and be a registered developer to use Apple's push notification server.

Comment: I guess if that's the only way of doing it, you should post these comments as an answer.